# Insert date value in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I tried to create a table to capture temperature

Something like this :

```
| Id | TemDate    | Temperature |   
|  1 | 2015-01-01 |          10 |
|  2 | 2015-01-02 |          25 |
```

After I created my temperature table, I used

```
 insert into temperature 
 values(1, '2015-01-01', 10);
```

and I got an error message saying: "not a valid month"

So I changed the code to

```
insert into temperature 
values(1, to_date('2015-01-01', 'yy-mm-dd'), 10);
```

after running the code the result table show tempdate as '01-Jan-2015' instead of '2015-01-01' as shown in the above table

I tired to used this code to fix the problem

```
insert into temperature 
values(1, to_date ('2015-Jan-01','yy-mm-dd'), 10);
```

but I still got '01-Jan-2015' not '2015-01-01'

How can I insert the date into the table so I can have the same format that look like '2015-01-01'? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Better specify the column order in the insert query. There might be mismatch in column order. Otherwise query looks fine.

Comment: I decided to take the leap and assume that you are really using Oracle, because MySQL does not support `to_date()`.

Comment: This is the format in which the sql developer represents the date. The object is stored correctly in the database.

Answer (score 3):

First, when inserting data into a table, provide the column names.

Second, in Oracle, you can use the `date` keyword and ISO standard dates:

```
insert into temperature(col1, col2, col3)  -- whatever they are
    values(1, date '2015-01-01', 10);
```

This, when you query this, you are going to get the date in Oracle's "presentation" format.  If you want it in another format, use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(datecol, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```